# Backbone history pushstate to hashtag IE9

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following code that checks pushstate and degrades to hashbang when not supported (IE9):

```
if(Backbone.history && !Backbone.History.started) { 
    if(!(window.history && history.pushState)) { 
        Backbone.history.start({ pushState: false, silent: true}); 
        var fragment = window.location.pathname.substr(
            Backbone.history.options.root.length); 
        var search = window.location.search; 
        Backbone.history.navigate(fragment + search, { trigger: true });
    }
    else {
        Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true });
    }
}
```

It functionally works, but the URL is transformed from:

http://dev.zwoop.be/home?page=1
to
http://dev.zwoop.be/home?page=1#home?page=1

which looks ugly.
I'm looking for an easy fix to replace the entire fragment behind the hostname with the hashtag.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
Backbone.history.navigate(fragment + search, { trigger: true });
```

by

```
var modified = (fragment + search).replace(/([^\/]*)(#[^#]*)$/g, '$2');
Backbone.history.navigate(modified, { trigger: true });
```

It will transform `http://dev.zwoop.be/home?page=1#home?page=1` into `http://dev.zwoop.be/#home?page=1`

Comment: Thanks but it gives me the same result. For some reason, it just adds whatever is navigated as a hashtag behind the entire path that was already there (incl. the fragment and query string).

Comment: Now that I think about it, there might be a valid reason for this behaviour: if an IE9 user sends a link to somebody else (or opens the same link) with a HTML5 History-enabled browser, the router will not consider the hashbang part to resolve the route. That means that `http://dev.zwoop.be/home?page=1#home?page=1` will work in non-IE9 browser whereas `http://dev.zwoop.be/#home?page=1` will not.

Comment: Hmm good point. But shouldn't there also be a way to overcome this behaviour by replacing the hashbang back with a slash when pushstate is available?

Comment: Probably. Better implement a router yourself than hacking the Backbone one.